# Imitate s3 and dynamo for development environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking to set up my staging server (many instances) to be able to spin up new instances at the press of a button. Ideally I'd just bring up a new docker instance whenever I need it, however each instance needs its own s3 and dynamo instance. If I have to I'll bring up real s3 and dynamodb instances through aws api or similar but I'd prefer to have containers to mimic s3 and dynamo. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) in a Docker container. Image can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/localstack/localstack/).

> LocalStack - A fully functional local AWS cloud stack

Then you need to override the AWS URL in the AWS SDK client to point to this container.

In Java it would look like this:

```
DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient = DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .endpointOverride(localstackUrl)
            .build();
```

Comment: Having a lot of issues with it unfortunately, the data doesn't seem to persist despite setting DATA_DIR because the s3 data isn't stored at that directory. Also I'm having a myriad of problems using the PHP s3 client with this container.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what `DATA_DIR` is, but I never tried to check the files stored in the container itself, I just use the API to save and load files. I'm using `localstack` for a lot of SNS, SQS, S3, DynamoDB tests without any problems. Check if this PHP example overriding the AWS URL works for you: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-new-regions-and-endpoints/

Comment: DATA_DIR is set in the composer.yml to persist data when you take down containers. Thanks for the link but that seems to be for something else. Here's the client constructor I'm using for s3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.AwsClient.html#___construct

Comment: I made an isue on the repo for my problem https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1292